# Package Your Python Django Application into a Reusable Component

Tags: python, django

I am trying to **Package my Django application** and for that I am following **django official docs** and I have successfully packaged my app But I have one problem with requirements of my app .

Since my app is using other packages too like **requests** etc. Now if any one install my package in their project , the package will be installed but its requirements not so surely it gives import error . Now I don't know that how to tell my package that installed its dependences too , I am sure I have to define these requirements somewhere but I don't know where ? OR I will follow the other path that place my requirement file in my package and tell users (from read me file) to install all dependencies from that file.

Also I have one more question , I am installing packages using this command **python setup.py install** , is there any other command from which I can install this package like **easy_install or pip** (My package is not in pypi can I still use pip if yes then how ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the setup.py file you can list your requirements under `install_requires`, see an example:

```
    install_requires=[
        'Pillow>=2.0',
        'django-appconf>=0.6',
    ],
```

About your second question, yes, you can install a package not published in PyPI using pip, [check this guide](http://guide.python-distribute.org/pip.html#installing-from-other-sources)

Comment: Yes the packages are installing but if I mentioned any package which is already there then the installation is stopped by saying requirement already satisfied for that package but it should continue with the installation of remaining packages but its not happening